# MVVMCorss - Change background color of Selected Item using MvxListView Not working

Tags: android, mvvmcross, android-viewmodel, mvxlistview

We are using MVVMCorss and showing the list using MvxListView. We want to add a background color for select item, but it still not working.

```
 <Mvx.MvxListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItems;SelectedItem MyChosenItem; ItemClick 
            ItemSelectedCommand;BackgroundColor BlackOrBlueColor(IsItemSelected)"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/_product"/>
```

We tried using converters like:

```
public class BlackOrBlueColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter<bool>
        {
            protected override Color Convert(bool value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value)
                    return Color.Black;
                else
                    return Color.Blue;
            }
        }
```

We have also tried all the available solutions found in `Stackoverflow`. Please, help us out here.

Comment: Have you tried using a color state list? That's more of an Android thing than MvvmCross, though.